# ASP.net Insert blank rows into Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, insert, sqldatasource

I have a gridview that is bound to a sqldatasource. The Gridview only has a pagesize of 10 and I would like each page to have 10 rows. Therefore if only 5 data rows exist then I would like to add an additional 5 empty rows. Is this easy to do?

Comment: Why you want to add blank rows? Much better if you retain your binding as is..

Comment: I need all the pages to have 10 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill your data into data set and count the number of rows retrieved then fill the remaining to the dataset with empty dataRows try this:
Suppose you have a DataSet dt filled with the table or data you want

```
int remainingRows=10 - dt.Rows.Count;
DataRow dr;
for (int i = 0; i < remainingRows; i++)
{
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = dr[1] = dr[2] = dr[3] = dr[4] = "";//index goes the no of cols in the table
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
dt.AcceptChanges();
grdView.DataSource = dt;
grdView.DataBind();
```

[You can see this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/280458/How-to-insert-empty-row-into-the-grid-view-in-dotn)

Answer (score 0):

For meeting your requirement , I think you shouldn't use sqldatasource to bind gridview instead of manual binding the datasource to gridview. you can encapsulate a datatable or dataview which each page have 10 rows as the datasource.