# How to add only row in gridView dynamically in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have created gridView in asp.net by writing following code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="dataGrdVwPatientDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Patient" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Modality" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Test" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Time" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Referring Physician" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="TotalRs" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Concession" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Paid" />
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Pending" />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now I want to add blank row in this gridView so that in future I can add values in that cells.

Comment: Are these examples satisfy your requirements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556692/asp-net-insert-blank-rows-into-gridview & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484383/how-to-add-blank-row-in-grid-view?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your gridview like below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dataGrdVwPatientDetails" DataKeyNames="ID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Patient" HeaderText="Patient" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Modality" HeaderText="Modality" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Test" HeaderText="Test" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Referring_Physician" HeaderText="Referring Physician" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalRs" HeaderText="TotalRs" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Concession" HeaderText="Concession" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Paid" HeaderText="Paid" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Pending" HeaderText="Pending" />
 </Columns>
```

And then your sql query should be like below:

```
select ID, patient, modality, test, time, Referring_Physician, TotalRs, 
       consession, paid, pending
  from my_table
union all
select (max(ID) + 1) as ID, '' as patient, '' as modality, '' as test,
       '' as time, '' as Referring_Physician, '' as TotalRs, '' as consession,
       '' as paid, '' as pending
```

And when user will updates that string, you can use an *insert* query.